# How to move object along the path generated in Geometry Nodes in Blender 3.1?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

Is this feature not implemented? Or am I missing anything?
For example I take a curve and in geometry nodes apply random offset to its points. The output geometry is still a curve.
When I set object to follow tha path, it follows the original curve and not the deformed one...

Would be a very nice feature.

Comment: Have you added the GeometryNodes modifier to the Curve?

Comment: Added? Yes Geometry Nodes is in the list of modifiers and the visible curve itslef is deformed. But the object animated along this curve moves as if the curve has its original shape.

Comment: pls add a blend file so we can see what you have tried and help you

Comment: I suppose it can be an example: https://blend-exchange.com/b/AxggVymz/

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK this cannot be done with geometry nodes at the moment.

But you could animate the empty within geometry nodes like this:

[image]

Comment: That would probably actually suffice in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Almost a dupe of [@Chris' answer..](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265905/35559)

Done, now, so I'll just highlight the option of making a separate little GN '*Follow Curve*' modifier, which can be re-used on other objects/paths, and does evaluate previous modifiers on the selected path-curve.

[image]